# When to use Gradle subprojects and when to use Java packages

Tags: java, gradle

This is a question about the way projects should be build in Gradle, and when subprojects should be used rather than packages.

Let's imagine a small project:

The project is an API that is a level of abstraction on a REST API. The project handles cache invalidation, abstraction of objects (so you can call `user.setPassword` instead of doing the HTTPS request yourself).

For this aim, the project is set in 3 parts:

1. The public API, that contains the calls that should be available to the end-user
2. The internal cache validation system & replication of objects (classes such as `User`...)
3. The HTTPS handler (instead of having to create a raw HTTPS request everytime you want to request something, you query this part of the project that has methods such has `post(url, token, JsonParameters)`)

Before using Gradle, I would have set all those as separate Java packages.

Now that I'm using Gradle, it seemed obvious to me that the HTTPS handler should be a subproject, because it's completely independent from everything else. This way, Gradle won't recompile/retest it if it's not modified.

I'm not sure about whether the internal cache etc should be a subproject or just a package. From my understanding:

- package: the code is tightly tied to the main public code, which is not a problem here, but the end-user can access it, which is not good (since every class used by the public package needs to be public)
- subproject: the code is not tied to the main code, which essentially means that some code that is pretty similar in intent (public API & cache) is in two different places. I'm not sure whether it would be available to the end-user or not...

Also, when I declare a dependency on some project on MavenCentral (for example), I do get access on its dependencies, right? In this case, I want the user that imports my project to only have access to the 'public' part. I've seen in Android tutorials that you can specify a dependency level (as in, you can declare that some dependency is available in your public API or not). Is that a Android-Gradle specific feature or is it available on regular Gradle as well ? (I'm using Gradle version 4.4). If that's available, would the preferred solution to the problem be to write the cache etc in a subproject then import it in the main project this way ?